# XHR pure XML responseType

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

It is possible to configure `XHR` to receive an HTML document with

```
xhr.responseType = "document";
```

When the response is received, `xhr.responseXML` holds an HTML document, parsed against HTML namespace URI. You can check:

```
xhr.responseXML.children[0].namespaceURI === 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
```

How can I get a pure XML document response, not parsed as HTML, something like:

```
document.implementation.createDocument(null,'');
```

Comment: I have edited this to read more clearly - I hope. However, I am still not sure I understand what you want. Please read over the edited version to make sure it makes sense. I believe what you are asking is how to get XML back from a request instead of getting XHTML back.

Comment: @DanLowe, your edit is welcome, and yes, i need XML, i wish to prevent  the browser engine to parse the resource as HTML casting XML `Element`s to `HTMLElement`s but i just found out that i made a silly question as it seems xhr response sets xhtml's namespace to `.html` files and `null` namespace to `.xml` files, as expected and needed (Chromium at least does it), i'll close the Q, thanks !

Comment: Closing is your choice, of course, but you could also add an answer yourself (and optionally, after 2 days mark it as accepted).

Comment: ok i'll keep this Q as is, as a reference, with the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find documentation about this issue, but it seems (FF & Chromium at least) that the js engine parses the `xhr.responseXML` depending on the resource's file extension:
it casts to HTML `.html` files and to generic XML `.xml` files